# getIntArray returns 0 from my XML file

Tags: android, xml, getresource

Working on an SQLite database. I'm importing data from my XML file.
The problem I got is when I try to read my int array, I only get 0 as values.

Part of my XML file :

```
<integer-array name="difficulties">
    <item>8</item>
    <item>12</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>7</item>
</integer-array>
```

How I am getting the array :

```
public int[] getDifficulties() {
    Resources res = this.getResources();
    return res.getIntArray(R.array.words);
}
```

How I am testing the array :

```
int[] test = getDifficulties();
for(int i=0; i<test.length; i++) {
    Log.i("MESSAGE", Integer.toString(test[i]));
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: should be: res.getIntArray(R.array.difficulties);

Comment: `words` != `difficulties`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not accessing your `difficulties` array correctly. Replace `return res.getIntArray(R.array.words);` with `return res.getIntArray(R.array.difficulties);`

Comment: oh ok I thought it had to be the XML file name. Working, thx!